# Ruby ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby, activerecord, heroku

I'm trying to learn on my own ruby database relations. 
I have a relation of 1 "Category" to many "Products" and I'm trying to add a product to the remote database (heroku server).

TIMESTAMP_create_products.rb

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :products, primary_key: 'product_id' do |p|
            p.index :product_id
            p.string :name
            p.decimal :price
            p.references :categories, index: true
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :products
    end
end
```

TIMETSTAMP_create_categories.rb

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :categories, primary_key: 'category_id' do |c|
      c.index :category_id
            c.string :name
            c.integer :parentId
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :categories
    end
end
```

model.rb

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "product_id"
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    belongs_to :categories, class_name: "Categories", foreign_key: 'category_id'
end

class Categories < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "category_id"
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    has_many :products, class_name: "Products"
end
```

I add manually a category to the database and every time I try to execute the code:

```
Products.create(name: "name1", price: "1.1", categories: Categories.find(1))
```

It gives me the output:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError can't write unknown attribute `category_id`

Is there anything missing here? I don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: Do you have a really good reason for going against ActiveRecord naming conventions?

Comment: No, I'm just exploring all the options, but thanks I will take a look on the naming conventions, maybe that's a reason for these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with singular / plural.

In your migration, to create the table `products`, you have the line:

```
p.references :categories, index: true
```

This should add to your table the column `categories_id`.

However, in the `Products` model, the foreign key is set to `category_id`. So when you try to attach a category to a production, it's trying to write the ID of the category to the column `category_id` of the table `categories`, which doesn't exists.

By changing the reference name in the products migration, everything should work fine:

```
create_table :products, primary_key: 'product_id' do |p|
  p.index :product_id
  p.string :name
  p.decimal :price
  p.references :category, index: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks you :)
You help me on my way, definitely the problem was with plural also changing this it worked:
Products.create(name: "name1", price: "1.1", category: Categories.find(1))